# HIbernate configuration file load fast

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

How to load a the hibernate configuration and mapping file offline using classpath refers to current package.
While loading online for each run it takes lots of time to fetch the configuration and mapping .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, accessing files on the classpath should be quick so you should really work out exactly what's taking the time. I'm guessing it's not the file access (unless you have some funky remote classloader).

If loading the configuration object is really what's taking the time, you could always serialize the object to a binary file and deserialize it later since [Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) implements `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: Sorry mistake in my question Actually while loading online its takes time and in offline classpath refers the current package

Comment: You haven't explained yourself well at all. Try again giving as much detail as possible and some sample code